# Command-line tool enabling tagging and related tags functionality

Tags: shell-script, command-line, files, scripting, filesystems

Is there a command-line tool that enables to give a file more attributes than a name?
For example, we have a file called `ubuntu.pdf` and we give it tags like `command-line`, `shell`, `nautilus`, `my_favourite_stuff`, `whatever_else` and a file `linux.pdf` with tags `shell`, `command-line`, `ln`, `best_book`

and than I would like to have a command

```
$ tagged shell
```

and it will output

```
  file: path_to/ubuntu.pdf, path_to/linux.pdf
  related_tags: command-line(2), shell(1), nautilus(1),...
```

note that related_tags are sorted with a number telling how many files are tagged with particular related tag. It works as a tag cloud in a command-line.

Can we achieve this behavior in command-line (with hardlinks, symbolic-links, shell-scripting, whatever)?

Comment: Tags are comments, content is code. They're *going* to get out of sync. "What is a file, exactly?" is not an idle question here, it has teeth. And tentacles, and a beak, and quite a collection of corpses litter the sea floor below. For instance, getting any GUI to work with your tags, ...

Comment: this sounds like the `man` page `apropos` feature, which searches the 4th line (usually)  just after the `Name` header for the specified target word. Too bad `.pdf` files don't allow something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux file systems do have capabilities for extended attributes, [Stephen shows in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/765405/596938).

But: many, probably most, graphical editors of various types will not truncate a file, then fill the same file with new content when you click on "safe". They instead make a new file, and rename it to original file name.

In that action, these extended file attributes get lost, because they stick to the actual last file, not the file name.

So, you really can't "safely" implement something like that on filesystem basis alone. You need database, with mapping of file names to tags.

So, while there is databases for e.g. photos or songs, nothing I think for files in general.

Writing that would not be hard - sqlite is easy to use for writing simple databases like this from shell scripts or Python or c++ or Go, but it would be something nobody but you used.

Probably should stick to original desktop search engines, as brought by the gnome in shape of tracker-miner!

Answer (score 1):

You could store tags in extended attributes (see [`man setfattr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setfattr.1.html) and [`man getfattr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getfattr.1.html) for details), and implements tag exploration commands using those. The benefit of using extended attributes is that they can be copied/moved with the files they are attached to (*e.g.* using `cp --preserve=all` on Linux).

The main disadvantage is that you’d have to list extended attributes on all the files you care about to construct tag clouds, which may end up being expensive.